# Why i can not set model to html select list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in asp.net mvc and and try to bind the model to html select list,in action write this code for bind to model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myModel=new Modal();
            myModel.RequestMode = "A";
            return View(myModel);
        }
```

and this is my html code:

```
<select>
    <option value=@Html.NameFor(x => x.RequestMode)>@Html.NameFor(x => x.RequestMode)</option>
</select>
```

but when run that app,in select list show RequestMode!,and don't show A char,how can i solve my problem?thanks

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor()`, not `NameFor()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for answer,that work!